# Память в Python. В чем отличие функций pympler.asizeof и sys.getsizeof, возвращающих размер измеряемого объекта?

Tags: python, память

Посмотрев одно из [выступлений](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0vbuIDOV4c&t=178s) Pycon о использовании памяти в Python стало интересно в чем в действительности различие функций модуля pympler.asizeof и sys.getsizeof. Для наглядности рассмотрим пример где измеряется размеры различных объектов.

```
from pympler import asizeof
from collections import namedtuple
from sys import getsizeof


class CLASS:
    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.x3 = x3


class SLOTS:
    __slots__ = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']

    def __init__(self, x1, x2, x3):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.x3 = x3


NTUPLE = namedtuple('NTUPLE', 'x1 x2 x3')

tpl = ('str', 111, 22.22)
ntuple = NTUPLE('str', 111, 22.22)
vClass = CLASS('str', 111, 22.22)
vSlots = SLOTS('str', 111, 22.22)

print('Pympler#',
      'namedtuple:', asizeof.asizeof(ntuple),
      'tuple:', asizeof.asizeof(tpl),
      'class:', asizeof.asizeof(vClass),
      'slots:', asizeof.asizeof(vSlots))
print('Sys#',
      'namedtuple:', getsizeof(ntuple),
      'tuple:', getsizeof(tpl),
      'class:', getsizeof(vClass),
      'slots:', getsizeof(vSlots))
```

Вывод:

```
Pympler# namedtuple: 184 tuple: 184 class: 448 slots: 176
Sys# namedtuple: 72 tuple: 72 class: 56 slots: 64
```

В данном примере я для себя хотел понять какая из структур занимает меньше всего места, но при использовании `asizeof.asizeof` наименьшим объектом является slots, а при измерении функцией `getsizeof`, наименьшим объектом является class. 
В результате поиска я не смог найти подробного описания отличий данных функций, в видео выступающий только лишь отметил, что `getsizeof` возвращает размер без, например, размера dict объекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция sys.getsizeof возвращает размер переданного ей обьекта, этот размер не включает в себя сложные структуры классов и т.д.

Функция pympler.asizeof - рекурсивно ищет всё вложенние поля и элементы, и отображает общий размер обьекта

p.s. хочу заметить то, что размер получаемый pympler.asizeof тоже может являться не точным, функция пытается собрать полный размер обьекта, но со сложными структурами данных это не всегда получается

Comment: А какие более правильные варианты получения размеров объектов в Python?

Comment: @AlexNasov я думаю что pympler это лучший способ.. узнать 100% точный размер очень сложных обьектов - невозможно